# Need a calculated value in models in Django

Tags: python, django

I want a calculated value in models.py. Below is the file `models.py`. I manage to get the `price` as expected but the `price` doesn't appear as one of the field. What I mean is, when I enter `delivery_price` and `support_price`, the `price` field should be calculated and be shown in the below page itself (attached image). Is this possible or am I getting something wrong?

```
delivery_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0,default=0)
support_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0,default=0)

#def get_price(self):
#    "Returns the price."
#    return (self.delivery_price + self.support_price)
#price = property(get_price)

price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0,editable=False)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.price = self.delivery_price + self.support_price
    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the reason for denormalization? Instead of `property` you can also use `cached_property` if performance is concerning you.

Comment: I also don't get the point of having `DecimalField` with `decimal_places=0`.

Answer (score 2):

editable=False means the field won't show up in Django admin. Instead in your admin.py ModelAdmin make it a read only field.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyModel
    readonly_fields = ('price',)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal right! The above code should be put in `admin.py`.

Comment: But is it going to auto populate the value of `price`? I am not getting the calculated value in `price`

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal Your `save` method in the model class takes care for the `price`. In the admin you can't see the value for `price` before you save the form. You have to add a product, submit the form, and after that the `price` will be displayed.

Comment: It must get populated as per your code. Are you looking for a realtime update ? You will have to save it and open again to see the new price.

Comment: I see...I would have wished if I was able to see the price as soon as I enter delivery price and support price. I do get the price once I submit the form

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal For that you'll need JavaScript and a lot of thinkering. You can't see the price as soon as you enter the other values, because the `save` method is not yet called.